# access twitter HomeTimeline of user

Tags: python, python-twitter

I am trying to develop a **gtk3** desktop application using **python** to perform the basic twitter functions like accessing the home timeline of a user, making tweets etc.

I am using python-twitter library, but am unable to find the API call for the purpose. I checked and saw there were a few [patches](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=152sig2=FcClNAvu_XLKZaL1G7UeJw) , but they dont seem to work. the rest of the functions I am able to accomplish using the library.

I need help!!!

[edit]
this is the error i am facing when i tried using a fork of the python-twitter library, as given on: http://github.com/jaytaylor/python-twitter-api

```
Error:
>>api.getUserTimeline('gaurav_sood91')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "twitter.py", line 2646, in getUserTimeline
    self._checkForTwitterError(data)
  File "twitter.py", line 3861, in _checkForTwitterError
    if data.has_key('next_cursor'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Comment: What have you tried? I see some examples about what you're asking in the [project home](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/). Are you having maybe authentication problems?

Comment: there was a github repo, [link]http://github.com/jaytaylor/python-twitter-api[/link] i tried using that, but was unable to use any specific method of the api invloving retrieving status messages etc, even though i saw the methods were present. an error was 
constantly being shown to me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "twitter.py", line 2646, in getUserTimeline
    self._checkForTwitterError(data)
  File "twitter.py", line 3861, in _checkForTwitterError
    if data.has_key('next_cursor'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'has_ke

Comment: Please improve your question by adding that information to the question.

Comment: i added the error i am getting. even though i tried getUserTimeline() function. i was unable to get how to use the getHomeTimeline() function

Answer (score 2):

Using the [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) module from code.google.com, documentation [here](http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html).

Accessing user timelines:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline('@gaurav_sood91')
print [s.text for s in statuses]
```

Posting tweets:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',      
                  access_token_key='access_token',   
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
status = api.PostUpdate('This is my update text.')
```

**Edit for applying GetHomeTimeline patch**:

**Disclaimer: I'm on Windows, so you may need to change these steps a bit.**

- Download [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/downloads/detail?name=python-twitter-0.8.2.tar.gz)
- Extract to folder
- Download 0002-Support-for-home-timeline.patch file from [issue 152](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=152)
- Copy/move patch file to root of extracted python-twitter directory (there should be a file named twitter.py in this dir)
- Run command: `patch twitter.py 0002-Support-for-home-timeline.patch`, you should get a message that patch succeeded
- In same directory, run command: `python setup.py install`
- Run interactive python shell: `import twitter`, `dir(twitter.Api)`

You should see the GetHomeTimeline method listed.

**Update for GetHomeTimeline:**

Found patch in issue 152 that works well using [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth) and JSON parse method that is now part of Status class. Sample code:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',      
                  access_token_key='access_token',   
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
statuses = api.GetHomeTimeline()
print [s.text for s in statuses]
```

Comment: that i know. but what i get via the GetUserTimeline() function is only the tweets i make, or replies i give. it does not give me the tweets of people i follow. that comes under the HomeTimeline, which is not given in python-twitter. i gave a link of a patch which is supposed to have added that functionality to it, but am unable to make it work

Comment: Updated answer with link to patch for python-twitter which adds status/home_timeline functionality.

Comment: one question: i did not get how to apply the patch.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix/Linux?

Comment: i did the steps. then patch was successfully installed and then re-installed the python-twitter library. only thing is using the api call. i tried calling it with userid or screen_name as arguments, by seem to get the following error:
http://bpaste.net/show/21144/

Comment: My original examples for posting tweets and retrieving home timeline were incorrect. You need to use OAuth to authenticate for posting or getting home timeline. Examples updated with link to information on OAuth in the Twitter dev pages.

Comment: After creating an account and authenticating with OAuth, I'm experiencing the same problems. I added a _username property to the Api object, but it looks like there are JSON parsing methods not implemented for home timelines.

Comment: Did some more research and found a patch that worked for python-twitter: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=152